# Android emulator won't start in Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, 64-bit

I'm trying to start emulator-arm but it seems to get stuck and never shows the emulator gui. This is my command

```
emulator-arm -avd Android403 -verbose
```

And this is the printout:

```
emulator: found SDK root at /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 15
emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-15/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-15/skins
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/xxxx/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-15/skins/WVGA800/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.touchScreen = yes
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.camera = no
  hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels = 640
  hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels = 480
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.fakeCamera = back
  hw.webcam.count = 6
  hw.webcam.0.name = webcam0
  hw.webcam.1.name = webcam1
  hw.webcam.2.name = webcam2
  hw.webcam.3.name = webcam3
  hw.webcam.4.name = webcam4
  hw.webcam.5.name = webcam5
  hw.webcam.0.direction = front
  hw.webcam.1.direction = back
  hw.webcam.2.direction = front
  hw.webcam.3.direction = front
  hw.webcam.4.direction = front
  hw.webcam.5.direction = front
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 166m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 66m
  disk.snapStorage.path = 
  avd.name = Android403
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "development/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 development/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator-arm -android-hw /home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xa600000,initfile=/home/xxxx/development/android-sdk-linux_x86/system-images/android-15/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-xxxx/emulator-wDcx8t
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now a608000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x4200000,file=/home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/xxxx/.android/avd/Android403.avd/cache.img
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=2
```

And it never gets any longer. It also sends a DNS-request of my computers hostname (and gets an answer!). When I cancel the emulator with ctrl-c the gui shows up for a fraction of a second before the process is killed.

I'm running 64-bit Linux but have 32-bit java installed. The same thing happens if I start the emulator from within Eclipse (of course).

Have anyone seen this? I've googling on this but seems people only have other emulator startup problems.

I think it something to do with my 64-bit system.

Comment: Try to run it with the command simply emulator -avd Android403 -verbose Is the result the same?

Comment: Try installing ia32-libs. Read somewhere that it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was amazingly solved today when I updated my OS (which I usually do at least once a week). 
3 packages where updated. Among them:

emul-linux-x86-baselibs-20120127
emul-linux-x86-xlibs-20120127

Previous versions where:

emul-linux-x86-baselibs-20110928
emul-linux-x86-xlibs-20110928

Didn't work with the old versions. But fixed with new versions of those libs.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `-noaudio` flag fixed this issue for me on RHEL6. And I did *not* need to rename `libOpenglRender.so` as some have suggested.

For example:

```
emulator -avd avdNameHere -verbose -noaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be the emulator trying to load the wrong snapshot, try

```
$ emulator -avd Android403 -verbose -no-snapshot-load
```

also notice that it's not needed to specify the architecture because the one that matches your avd will be selected.